# how to send password while executing python script on a remote machine

Tags: python

I have a python script which I want to execute on a remote machine.
I am doing it using below command

```
import os

cmd="cat myonboarding.py | ssh cloud-user@10.80.99.45 python"

os.system(cmd)
```

How ever while executing the script, password prompt pops up.
How to send password here?

Regards,
Sridevi

Comment: With sshpass, there other people with the same question
https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Comment: You might consider [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) module helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to send a password, but set up key-based authentication ([tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server)). This is the most convenient and commonly used way to log in via SSH without typing a password.